# JavaFx - Open window next to main windows

Tags: java, javafx, java-8

I am using JavaFx and I want open a new window next to the first window like in the picture. I can open a new window but its always on the first. How can i do that?

[image: Windows next to each other.]

```
   Parent detailsPanel = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/DetailsPanel.fxml"));
    Stage stage = new Stage();

    stage.setTitle("Details");
    stage.setScene(new Scene(detailsPanel));
    stage.setResizable(false);
    stage.show();
```

Comment: What do you mean with 'on the main' ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do

```
double windowGap = 5 ;
Stage currentStage = ... ; // the current window...

stage.setX(currentStage.getX() + currentStage.getWidth() + windowGap);
stage.setY(currentStage.getY());
```